# array.map issue with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

S0 im trying to set an array of objects in state before the component mounts, then when it renders, loop through those objects. But i cant seem to get the array.map to work. Suggestions?

The code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ComponentContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            apiData: []

        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(localStorage.getItem('menu_url'))
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ 'apiData': response.data.view.sections }); (This is an array, currently with 1 object in it)
            });
    }

    render() {

        console.log('Axios response to state:', this.state.apiData); (this works, and show the 1 object)

        return (
            <div>
                <p>test</p>
                {this.state.apiData.map((index, sections) => (
                    <p key={index}>Value: {sections}</p> (this is where i have the issue)
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So inside the state apiData is a single object (there could be many), and I need to drill into that object, which contains another array of objects (12 i think),  These objects are what i need to display data.

This where im lost.

Comment: You have your arguments reversed should be `.map((sections, index) => ...`

Comment: You have index and sections reversed in your map call. The item comes first. But you can do `sections.map(...)` inside `apiData.map(...)`, or hand it off to another component to render the inner list. `<SectionItemList section={section} />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey index and sections are not in the right order. Change it to this, this should work:

```
{this.state.apiData.map((sections, index) => (
                    <p key={index}>Value: {sections}</p> (this is where i have the issue)
                ))}
```